# Redmine was initialized because I changed the docker volume folder. Is there a way to reverse it?

Tags: docker, redmine, volume

Our project uses redmine.
I am using Redmine on my docker.

My mistake was that redmine was initialized after changing the volume folder in the redmine container.
We copied all the files in the original volume folder to the new volume folder, but our redmine project did not come back.

How do I get back to our redmine project?

Comment: The volume folder has been changed, and the / var / lib / docker / overlay2 subfolder has also been changed. volume folder to normal, the / var / lib / docker / overlay2 subfolder did not come back.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the old docker-volume then simply link that volume to the newly created container.

Take reference from https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes

For Example

`$ docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  -v myvol2:/app \
  nginx:latest`

Comment: thank you.
It was your way.
The volume folder is back.

But
redmine could not come back.
redmine is still initialized.

Comment: similary if you try to run `docker ps -a` you can find out previously created redmine-container. let me see the output if that container is still existing.

Comment: `woojin-1:~ yeon-woojin$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
78002eeab4cd        redmine:latest      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:32779->3000/tcp   red-001
f18970ed1c8c        redmine:latest      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:32778->3000/tcp   redmine-test`

red-001 is new container.

Comment: red-001 is new container, howerver "redmine-test" container- was it working fine as you were expecting ?

Comment: The "redmine-test" container is the container that changed the volume folder. The "redmine-test" container has redmine initialized.
I want to restore the redmine by reverting the "redmine-test" container.

Comment: and what is the output of `docker volume ls` ?

Comment: woojin-1:~ yeon-woojin$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               167258e27f042586d123f285a7c10fe62e57f131d09efd2e69fa7e74360671df
local               2ded7329fcad8fae23df772d6f7b2ca15e09b05ed884aeb0860aa4e4c7f2c73e
local               35dfc183c098e178e9f0a749e55cf89cb08b608d6ab4b8360ca0b4871c4d0a98
local               6a88c0293d59406c1ff22604cdea1037d444f7fd968e9f9d4e64298250f0d20e
local               6c0c8c72bb082c16d9d3e295feb669b00f3bb2078170c64a9e27c385482d56b2

Comment: local               6fbae333abeaab59880e0d8c5f76fae627e90c8bd65cb4610788953947d181d9
local               730052fb6466cf9822e9ffec4f4ffd989af47d09c415f92b360a4abf63a64dbc
local               785ddb48d2ef7b8f82c3be3d880934f93f2dd5ca327c7b35e92da5d932d7fcc1
local               8a6ea08725fd3303e8aeeabfdac7fb2a63e6125de516b86d04ba95e7132097de
local               8e83e973447ac703d67a47fc5c26bb46c691c8638e8773be265d2e42cb8f40a7

Comment: local               8f8e2656b7a5e961dec6c07e90582d78501d66b72f35ead5067a2de79eb40c72
local               9b320fffb97725133fbeb1aed2920a1b12a6673aeac9fbe7860ba423eb4e42ac
local               a3f98da526022c2f904dacfa75f0d3016056d4b04c81ba5c2fee9a555ceba828
local               d2eecd540ae27bef6eb1da64905504f5ef817071693cda8edf9fae2fe2ff1081
local               ddb66b095aa9cccb2212f56efbbb92c5419e2e92f45fbca9257e9644f2a8d564

Comment: local               e4ec8be5de1b6c45e1754a2d4f33ace27ba763254de494ade37520875988d2ad
local               f8c1cce8747a696fe8344e1f00f0a7c13410aaef9a0326554debe23125b34c33
local               null

Comment: The original mount value for redmine-test container is below.

"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "a3f98da526022c2f904dacfa75f0d3016056d4b04c81ba5c2fee9a555ceba828",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/a3f98da526022c2f904dacfa75f0d3016056d4b04c81ba5c2fee9a555ceba828/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/redmine/files",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],

Comment: And according to your advice, I entered "docker run -d --name redmine-test-new -v a3f98da526022c2f904dacfa75f0d3016056d4b04c81ba5c2fee9a555ceba828: / usr / src / redmine / files redmine: latest".

Comment: I expected redmine to be a redmine restored to the redmine-test-new container, but it was still an initialized RedMine.